# reducing size of a button in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

My Activity_main.xml looks like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/UsernameText"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/UsernameText"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PasswordText"
                android:width="250dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/PasswordText"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MyButton"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Linear View :

[image]

Horizontal View:
[image]

How do I make the Button size smaller? Also how do I make both views approximately similar?

Answer (score 2):

It is always advisable to have different layouts to support both orientation. Have two different xml layout files under the resource folder layout-port and layout-land. You can read this page for better understanding on how its done. [Multiple screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/UsernameText"
                    android:width="250dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:hint="@string/UsernameText"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/PasswordText"
                    android:width="250dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/PasswordText"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />


        <Button
                android:id="@+id/MyButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This completely fills up the screen when on horizontal mode

Comment: change parent layout android:layout_height="wrap_content"